# C# PDFsharp. How to skip past errors?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, pdfsharp

I am converting and merging 750k pages into 1/2 million multi-page PDFs in a `WinForm` program.

I have my PDF write function inside a `try catch` block but `PDFSharp` keeps throwing up assertion failures with a `dialogue box`. 
If I hit an *error* I just want the program to log the exception details and go to the next set of files because I won't be awake in the middle of the night to press `Ignore`.

How could I stop this in `C#` please? 
Setting to release instead of debug doesn't work.

Comment: PDFsharp is *internally* displaying a message box?  Honestly, I'd complain pretty loudly to the vendor if that's the case.  It shouldn't even *reference* the UI API, let alone invoke it.  (Imagine for example using the product on a web server...)

Comment: any code that you could provided? To be honest it is not perfectly clear what are you trying to do and what happens.

Comment: Please add a minimal piece of code that produces the error. I am aware that it will depend on input, too. But that way we can come up at least with some theories to be falsified or confirmed.

Comment: @David The DEBUG build uses `Debug.Assert` to show potential problems. `Debug.Assert` does nothing with a RELEASE build. The OP does not use PDFsharp properly or uses an inappropriate build.

Comment: Thanks to all. Using the latest Nuget package stopped the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assertions are no exception.

Assertions only show with the DEBUG build, not the RELEASE build. So use the RELEASE build properly and no assertions will show up. Maybe try the latest NuGet packages.

Comment: I selected release build on the source window and in the assembly but it's still happening, a dialogue window pops up with the title "Assertion:Failed" and details of the pdf error with Abort, Retry & Ignore buttons. Te actual errors I'm not interested in at the moment. I am working with an included pdfsharp project so I'm just trying out the nuget package, which is a later version.

Comment: If the DLLs were compiled with a different solution and the DEBUG setting then setting your solution to RELEASE will not deactivate the `Debug.Assert`. You have to compile PDFsharp with the RELEASE setting or use the NuGet packages that are RELEASE. I cannot know what you are doing, but that is how RELEASE and `Debug.Assert` work.

Comment: That's probably the reason. I had the PDFSharp source code project in the solution so I expected it to compile but as you can see I'm not  a VS expert. Working away unattended now, thanks for all the advice everybody.

Answer (score 0):

To belatedly clarify, using the *latest* Nuget package rather than adding the source code to the project fixed the problem.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.